# php - PDO not updating time()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having a problem with a PDO query that is executed every time someone posts a reply in my forum:

```
$time= time();  


$s = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE forum_topics SET last_post_user=:user, last_post_userid=:userid, last_post_time=:time, posts=posts+1 WHERE topic_id=:topicid");
                $s->bindParam(':user', $userdata['username']);
                $s->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
                $s->bindParam(':time', $time);
                $s->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
                $s->bindParam(':topicid', $topicid);
                            try {
                    $s->execute();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
```

The above query does actually update my database.. All fields, expect the `:time` is getting updated.

The structure in the database, for `last_post_time` is `int(20)`

I have no idea why it is not being updated - can someone see any issues? I don't get an error or anything..

Comment: Why your column type is `int` to save a time ?

Comment: try adding a type casting parameter to your `bindValue`, ex : PDO::PARAM_INT

Comment: @Rikesh that is how I've always done it, and it have always worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few questions:
Do you get any exception? Or just `last_post_time` in DB is empty (defaulted)? Is `$time= time()` assigning timestamp to `$time`?

You may also try replacing `:time` with `:post_time`

```
$s = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE forum_topics SET last_post_user=:user, last_post_userid=:userid, last_post_time=:post_time, posts=posts+1 WHERE topic_id=:topicid");
                $s->bindParam(':user', $userdata['username']);
                $s->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
                $s->bindParam(':post_time', $time);
                $s->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
                $s->bindParam(':topicid', $topicid);
                            try {
                    $s->execute();
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
```

You may also check internal logs of your DB to check if there is nothing wrong internally.